# What does the "see" mean in expression like "The deal will see..."?

Tags: meaning

This are some specific examples:

> 1. The deal will see first-quarter exports cut by 270,000 tonnes.
> 2. South Korean farmers are worried that the deal will see US produce pour into the country, threatening their livelihoods.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! You should probably mention what dictionaries you looked "see" up in and the meanings you considered, as well as the trouble you had applying those meanings to these contexts.

Answer (score 2):

It may sound strange to say that a deal can **see** something, but if you look at **see** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see), one of the definitions is

> to be the time or place when something happens

What it means is that the specified things will happen when the deal goes through.